# Show this one is a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

On a fixed interval $[0,T]$, let $(W_t)_{0\le t \le T}$ be a Brownian motion, and
$ (\gamma_t)_{0\le t \le T} $ a cadlag process. Let $$ M_t = exp ({\int_0^t\gamma_sdW_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\gamma_s^2ds}) \\$$
for $0 \le t \le T$

Show that $M_t$ is a martingale.

I started by applying the definition of martingale, which is $$E[M_s|\Im_t]=E[M_s\frac{M_t}{M_s}|\Im_t]$$
so$$E[M_s|\Im_t]=M_sE[\frac{M_t}{M_s}|\Im_t]$$
Then I tried to substitute $M_t = exp ({\int_0^t\gamma_sdW_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\gamma_s^2ds}) $

and $M_s = exp ({\int_0^s\gamma_sdW_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^s\gamma_s^2ds})$ into $E[\frac{M_t}{M_s}|\Im_t]$.

I am not sure i am heading on the right track and also after I did substitution I dont know how to use cadlag process properties to solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $(\gamma_t)_t$ is a cadlag process? A deterministic one? If $(\gamma_t)_t$ is not deterministic, then you need additional assumptions on $(\gamma_t)$ (otherwise the assertion might fail; for several reasons).

Comment: Sorry, it was just a typo. It is supposed to be $(\gamma_t)_{0\le t \le T}$ a cadlag process. Not sure if this makes sense to you now.

Comment: No, it doesn't; the claim is simply not correct. For an arbitrary cadlag process the stochastic integral $$\int_0^t \gamma_r \, dW_r$$ is, in general, not even well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Itô's lemma, then here is a hint:

Use Itô's lemma to show that
$$dM_t = - \gamma_t M_t dW_t.$$
The above immediately implies that $M_t$ is a (positive) martingale.

Comment: Why does this imply that $(M_t)_t$ is a martingale? It shows that it is a local martingale and (because of positivity) also a supermartingale. But how do you conclude that $(M_t)_t$ is a martingale without any further assumptions on $(\gamma_t)$?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Novikov's condition is sufficient, but that is perhaps too optimistic to assume. I was too much focused on finding an easy way.

Comment: Yea, I am familiar with Itô's lemma, so I kinda understand this. can you explain why $dM_t  = - \gamma_t M_t dW_t$ implies that $M_t$ is a martingale?

Comment: Note that one can write $dM_t = - \gamma_t M_t dW_s$ as
$M_t = -\int_{0}^{t} \gamma_s M_s dW_s.$
This is a stochastic integral w.r.t a martingale (namely Brownian motion). Hence, under certain conditions (like Novikov) on the process $(y_s)$ it is well known that $M_t$ is a martingale. It is certainly a local martingale, however proving it is a martingale requires more conditions as @saz pointed out.